# WordPress get user by meta data

Tags: wordpress

How can I retrieve all users registered in my WordPress blog having a particular meta data?

For example I have made an option to add a custom meta data for every registering users having meta key as `parent_id`. If I want to list all users having `parent_id` as `2` , then how can I do this?

Answer (score 116):

Since WP v3.1 it's ridiculously easy to search for a user by his/her meta key.

Use the function

```php
get_users($args)
```

([WP Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/))

The function takes an array of parameters, in your case you need

```php
get_users(array(
    'meta_key' => 'parent_id',
    'meta_value' => '42'
))
```

Comment: Excellent. I was trying to use the "meta_query" option, which was not working. This worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 47):

Simple way how to get one user by his metadata is:

```
$user = reset(
 get_users(
  array(
   'meta_key' => $meta_key,
   'meta_value' => $meta_value,
   'number' => 1
  )
 )
);
```

Comment: For anyone who only needs the user id. Add an array argument `'fields' => 'ids'`. This will make the query more lightweight.

Comment: @Sisir and    'count_total' => false,

Answer (score 15):

Here is how you can get users based on a custom role and multiple metadata keys,

```
$available_drivers = get_users(
            array(
                'role' => 'driver',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'approved',
                        'value' => true,
                        'compare' => '=='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'available',
                        'value' => true,
                        'compare' => '=='
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Explaining the above query, I want only those users who I assigned the role of driver, and they are approved and available. The approved and available are custom fields created using ACF as True/False fields.

If you have additional metadata to test, add another array element to the meta_query array.

Meanwhile checkout my open source at github.com/patrickingle